What are some (popular) references on variants of the classical gambler's ruin problem that exists in literature?
It is fascinating that the gambler's ruin problem which is so ubiquitous in modern probability theory (cf. the Levin-Peres text on Markov chain and Mixing Times) actually dates back to a letter from Pascal to Fermat written in the 1650s (cf. this manuscript by Oystein Ore ).
I wanted to see some mathematical research where variants of the classical gambler's ruin were studied (e.g. by accomodating multiple gamblers and/or letting the bet sizes for the rounds to be deterministic or non-deterministic variables, changing the rules for winning/losing a round, etc.).

Multi-dimensional generalizations (one player against $d$ other players) are explored by P. Lorek in Generalized Gambler's Ruin Problem: explicit formulas via Siegmund duality.
For the analogue on a ring or torus graph, see Generalized Gambler’s Ruin Problem by Chayes et al.
Further generalizations include The conditional gambler’s ruin problem with ties allowed.
